# jquery change function not working on Modal PopUp asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Dropdown change event function is not working in Bootstrap modal.

**My Modal PopUp**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="UpdateModelPopup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="UpdateModelPopup">Add Menu</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <h4>UserMenu</h4>
                            <hr />
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MenuNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MenuNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MenuCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MenuCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuProject, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MenuCode, new SelectList(ViewBag.menuProject_list), "--- Select Menu Project ---", new { @id="cbxMenuProject", @class = "form-control select" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuLevel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MenuLevel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MenuLevel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MenuName, new SelectList(" "), "--Select Menu Name--", new { @id="cbxMenuName", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MenuURL, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MenuURL, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MenuToolTip, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MenuToolTip, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MenuToolTip, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdateMenu" onclick="return AddMenu();">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**My JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LoadAddMenu() {
        $("#UpdateModelPopup").modal('show');
    };


    $("#cbxMenuProject").on('change', function () {
        alert('dasda');
    })

    $("#cbxMenuProject").change(function () {
        alert('dasda');
    })

    function AddMenu() {
        alert('dasda');
    }
</script>
```

When I change dropdown, change function of javascript is not working, Not sure why.

Before it was working on another page and it working fine, but after move code to modal popup, it stopped to working.

I'm using bootstrap 4 and Asp.Net MVC project

Comment: looks like you are never calling `LoadAddMenu()`

Answer (score 0):

There is two times Id - cbxMenuProject used, kindly use only one time id, Id should be unique for all attribute.

You can use class instead of Id if you want to give the same identifier of multiple elements.

Check is there any error in console or not.
If yes and it related to **$ is not defined** then add jquery.js reference before render your script. *Most common issue when working with Jquery*

Add your script functions in document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".cbxMenuProject").on('change', function () {
    alert('dasda');
  })

  $(".cbxMenuProject").change(function () {
    alert('dasda');
  })
});
```

OR $(function)...

```
$(function() {
    $(".cbxMenuProject").on('change', function () {
        alert('dasda');
      })

      $(".cbxMenuProject").change(function () {
        alert('dasda');
      })
});
```

Here I changed selecter "#" to "." for considering change id to class as it is duplicate, You've to change in your modal elements.